# Populate Specific Text from Selected Text File and get the Color associated with Specific Text

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a utility where a List of Textfiles is Populated in a Combobox. Then based on Selected item of Combobox I want to get the Specific text which is next to the word "material".
Now each of the textfile can have multiple "material" values. 
  These textfiles contain certain text in the format below,

```
MV_PL--0

material Aluminium
 color 0.752941 0.752941 0.752941
 specular_color 0.87451 0.87451 0.87451
 end

material Brass_Frosted
 color 0.811765 0.713726 0.478431
 specular_color 0.87451 0.803922 0.635294
 end
```

I managed to get the only the first value next to "material" in the Listbox. How can I get all the values listed next to "material" in each of the Textfile?

[CODE]

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim strPath As String = "C:\Users\Test\"
    Dim dirInfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(strPath)
    For Each file As FileInfo In dirInfo.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        FileComboBox.Items.Add(file.Name)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub FileComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FileComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted

    MatlListBox.Items.Clear()
    Dim strPath As String = "C:\Users\Test\"
    Dim strRead As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(strPath + FileComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString)

   Dim Material As String = strRead.Split(New String() {"material "}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1).Split(" ")(0)
   MatlListBox.Items.Add(Material)

End Sub
```

[/code]

Finally once I get the Specific Value next to "material" I need to convert the values available in next line "color 0.752941 0.752941 0.752941" to a color that can be assigned to a textbox backcolor. 
Kindly advise...

Comment: How do you interpret the color values?  I assume they are some kind of RGB values, but is that a "percentage"?  What are min/max values for them?  In .Net, RGB color values range from 0 to 255.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your reply. I too have been trying to work out those values. In the Parent Application for which I am developing the utility, it shows diferent color in Preview when each Material type is selected in Listbox. I Will keep trying on the color conversion. But can u help with populating all Material values from textfile into Listbox?

Comment: Well for one thing you Split strRead into a String, not an array of Strings.  You'd need to make Material an array and loop through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you can probably parse the file with some fancy RegEx, but I suck at those.  Here's a plain old line processing routine that extracts the name and color from the selected text file.  I haven't added any of the Else conditions which would occur if the file was badly formed or had an invalid value in one of the lines.  The implementation here makes use of a custom "Material" class that holds the name and color value.  Instances of Material are added to the ComboBox.  The overridden ToString() function within determines how the ComboBox displays the instance of Material.  When the SelectedIndex of the ComboBox changes, we cast the SelectedItem back to Material and use the values to change the Color of a TextBox:

```
Private Sub FileComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FileComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted
    Dim materials As New List(Of Material)
    Dim strPath As String = "C:\Users\Test\"
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines(strPath + FileComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString))
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
        If lines(i).StartsWith("material") AndAlso i < lines.Count - 1 Then
            Dim mat As New Material

            Dim values() As String
            values = lines(i).Split(" ")
            If values.Length >= 2 Then
                mat.Name = values(1)

                If lines(i + 1).StartsWith(" color") Then
                    values = lines(i + 1).Split(" ")
                    If values.Length >= 5 Then
                        Dim value As Double
                        Dim R, G, B As Byte
                        If Double.TryParse(values(2), value) Then
                            If value >= 0 And value <= 1 Then
                                R = value * 255

                                If Double.TryParse(values(3), value) Then
                                    If value >= 0 And value <= 1 Then
                                        G = value * 255

                                        If Double.TryParse(values(4), value) Then
                                            If value >= 0 And value <= 1 Then
                                                B = value * 255

                                                mat.Color = Color.FromArgb(R, G, B)
                                                materials.Add(mat)
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    materials.Sort()
    MatlListBox.DataSource = materials
End Sub

Private Class Material
    Implements IComparable(Of Material)

    Public Name As String
    Public Color As Color

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function

    Public Function CompareTo(other As Material) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of Material).CompareTo
        Return Me.Name.CompareTo(other.Name)
    End Function

End Class

Private Sub MatlListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MatlListBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    If MatlListBox.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        Dim mat As Material = DirectCast(MatlListBox.SelectedItem, Material)
        TextBox1.BackColor = mat.Color
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks idle_Mind.. I noticed that although it reads all the Material values it does not populate them in Listbox.. So I moved "  MatlListBox.Items.Add(mat)" line as follows,

Comment: Hmmm...I missed the space before "color" in the file.  See edit for changes...hold on.

Comment: I changed "color" to " color", then updated the array length check and incremented the indices being used for the RGB values.

Comment: Awesome Idle_Mind.. you are the Man... works flawlessly.. now only need to figure out to arrange them A-Z in Listbox..

Comment: We can make the Material Class Implement IComparable, then add the instances to a List(Of Material) that can be sorted.  Finally, set the DataSource Property of the ListBox to the List.  See changed code.

Comment: Thanks Idle_Mind.. As you had mentioned about bad formatting.. I came across one textfile where there was an extra space before the text color i.e. "  color" which caused error. I manually edited the source textfile and the code worked..I though to add a condition in the code so that it reads the extra space but that did not help.. I added "andalso" so that it can read both " color" and "  color" . Its not a showstopper but any workaround. ? This is the only bad formatted file I found.